# Apex class with namespace deploy via Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, namespace

I want to deploy using metadata API.
I have class `classes/MyPackage__UninstallClass.cls` with `MyPackage` namespace
`classes/MyPackage2__UninstallClass.cls` with `MyPackage2` namespace.
But when I try to deploy Salesforce give me an error message:

`File name mismatch with class name: UninstallClass`
I can not rename class as `MyPackage__UninstallClass`
Maybe it is necessary to add something in addition into `package.xml` or in `MyPackage__UninstallClass.cls-meta.xml`. What I should do?

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? You can't update a class in a managed package (that's what "managed" means).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First be sure that you are trying to update an unmanaged or unlocked package. You cannot update managed packages.

Second, your package,xml file needs to have the package name in the fullname parameter, but the Apex class name does not have a namespace. For example:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <fullName>MyPackage2</fullName>
        <types>
            <members>UninstallClass.cls</members>
            <name>ApexClass</name>
        </types>
        <version>42.0</version>
    </Package>
```

Lastly, be sure that the class name in your actual code matches the file name:

```
    public class UninstallClass {
```

Answer (score 0):

I do know if anyone is still having trouble with this but if you...

1. Rename your file name
2. Delete the meta.xml file and recreate it with the new name
3. Redeploy it

This worked for me. Also, you will need to make sure you delete your old file from the org